# Передача анонимного массива в функцию с++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Можно ли передать в функцию при вызове анонимный массив, как например со строкой?
Почему пример 2 не работает ? как сделать чтоб он заработал не используя лишних переменных ?

пример 1

```
void foo(char *arr) {
    cout << arr[2];
};

int main() {
    foo("123");
}
```

пример 2

```
void foo(int *arr) {
    cout << arr[2];
};

int main() {
    foo({1,2,3});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что конструкция вида `{1, 2, 3}` не является, как Вы выразились, анонимным массивом. Она называется [`braced-init-list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) и ведёт себя по-разному, в зависимости от контекста. В Вашей ситуации можно поступить следующим образом:

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<int> arr) {
    cout << arr.size();
    cout << arr[2];
};
```

Где [`std::initializer_list`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) - объект, который ведёт себя как контейнер и, по факту, содержит в себе пару указателей, поэтому не сильно нагружает run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Так как передаваемый массив у вас временный объект, то тип можно поменять на r-value ссылку или на константный массив. И ещё сделать функцию шаблоном для удобства обработки массивов разной длины.

```cpp
# include <iostream>
using std :: cout ;

template <size_t ars >
void foo(int ( &&  arr ) [ ars ] ) {
    cout << arr[2];
}

template <size_t ars >
void foo(int const ( & arr ) [ ars ] ) {
    cout << arr[2];
}

int main() {
    foo({1,2,3});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, пример со строкой не компилируется начиная с C++11. Если ваш компилятор такое принимает, он плохо настроен.

Строки можно передавать, на выбор, как одно из: `std::string_view`, `const std::string &`, `const char *`.

Во-вторых, раз указатель неконстантный, странно пытаться передать туда временный объект. Либо навесить `const`, либо, если хотите что-то туда писать, отказаться от временных объектов - потому что как после вызова функици считать из них результат?

---

`std::initializer_list`, предложенный в соседнем ответе, плох тем, что ничего кроме `{...}` туда передать уже не получится (например, именованный массив). А ссылка на массив из другого ответа плоха тем, что в нее можно передать только массив (именованный или нет), и нельзя - кусок массива, `vector`, и т.п.

В С++20 для этих целей появился [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (который хранит в себе указатель и размер):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void foo(std::span<const int> arr) {
    std::cout << arr[2] << '\n';
};

int main() {
    foo({{1,2,3,4}}); // Обратите внимание на двойные фигурные скобки.

    int arr[] = {5,6,7,8};
    foo(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для создания временного массива можно использовать `::std::array`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int * arr)
{
    ::std::cout << arr[2];
}

int main()
{
    foo(::std::array{1,2,3}.data());
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo(int+*+p_items)%0A%7B%0A++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+p_items%5B2%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo(::std::array%7B1,2,3%7D.data())%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score -1):

Работает даже в ANSI C:

```
void foo(int *arr) {
    cout << arr[2];
};

int main() {
    foo((int[]){1,2,3});
}
```

Comment: к сожалению **только** в Си такое разрешается.